# How to resolve "Failed to download repository information"?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, package-management

Whenever I try to install anything with the Ubuntu Software Center, the following error appears.

> #### Failed to download repository information
>
> Check your Internet connection.
>
> `E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index (1)`

Comment: The above does not work for me. I notice when running "apt-get update" the concatenated string contains the IP for this device (in my case 10.1.1.4), NOT the nameserver (10.1.1.1). It is then unable to connect.

Comment: I'd like to add this as an answer to this protected question, but don't have the rep here yet.  Anyway, I ran into this problem.  In my case I had forgotten I had added a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for a 3rd party package from `https://z.litestack.com/v1/repo/ubuntu/`.  That URL ceased to resolve (superseded by instructions at http://zerovm.org/download.htm), so `apt-get` would always end up tripping over that.  `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerovm-precise.list` fixed it for me.

Comment: I had this problem with 17.04, upgrading to 17.10 solved the problem

Answer (score 87):

Try cleaning up your apt-cache and running any updates

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still have issues, then change your repo mirror:
Open **Update Manager** or **Software Updater**, then click **Settings > Ubuntu Software** tab, then select **Other** from the **Download From** menu and click the <kbd>Select Best Server</kbd> button. Once finished, the best server will show up selected (highlighted), so just click the  <kbd>Choose Server</kbd> button. Now try updating/upgrading again.

Comment: You rock! This fixed my VMware Ubuntu! I was kind of freaking out that I'll have to re-install it but this worked great.

Comment: Don't get too excited Georgi, your Linux machine will break again I promise lol

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu netbook edition (10.10). When I tell it to *Select Best Server*, it goes through all 361 of them and then concludes, "No suitable download server was found. Please check your Internet connection." Yet, I can access the internet just fine.

Comment: I tried and I got 'no suitable server found.' Pls help.

Comment: `sudo apt clean` was the ticket. I had to remove some items from my `/etc/apt/sources.list` that were failing too.

Comment: You may also need this: `sudo apt install ca-certificates`. See here: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/certificate-verification-failed/61064/5?u=ercaguy

Answer (score 39):

"Software Updater" will give same error message for issues like:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/crass/ufraw/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

**Solution**:  Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software -> Click on offending entry and hit Remove (OR simply un-check so its ignored yet visible for later)

Another way to un-check the bad entries is to

```
cd /etc/apt
grep -r some_string *
```

for example

```
grep -r ufraw /etc/apt
```

which will return the file containing string ufraw so then edit that file and comment out the line mentioning string  ufraw

This shuts off updates to the package linked to this file ... the symptom will go away ... problem often due to using a package not yet customized for the version of OS you are on

Comment: Note this can also apply if "cdrom" is in the repo list, see http://askubuntu.com/a/386048/254

Comment: This is the correct answer; the problem is that the error message does not indicate *which* entry is the offending one.  :(  But yes, once you can figure that out, works like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me, too.  I ran into this problem when I installed the blueman and bluez5 packages to support my Microsoft BT mouse.  Clearing the checkboxes next to these packages on the "Other Software" tab in  Software & Update fixed it.

Comment: That was it, "cdrom" was the offender (I'm running a virtual machine), unchecked it and the problem went away

Comment: For me there was an error telling me which package was the culprit on running `sudo apt update` in the terminal, disabling that one seemed to work

Comment: sudo apt-get update will show you which link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same issue I'm also facing with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My device is connected to a 'metered connection'(I'm thinking the issue is because I have set this connection as metered. Not sure though). But I have found a way to update even after this error.

1. Click on the 'settings' option below that error message and it will open the 'software & Updates'.
2. Now just close the 'Software & Updates' window and you will see the updates are available for download and installing.

I don't know the reason behind this error. If someone could add upon this it will be helpful. But this definitely works. I have done this for more than two weeks.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 4):

Assure cdrom is unchecked then cut and paste entire set of below commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`  
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when upgrading from 18.10 to the newest version. In my case the reason was that I had some packages marked as kept back. This is what I did.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1 
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

I simply removed them along with their dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt remove libodbc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
freetds-bin libodbc1
```

Then the following sequence of commands led me to the successful upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

there is something that worked for me:

please goto update manager settings > under Ubuntu software tab uncheck "cdrom with Ubuntu 12.04 'precise pangolin'"

then under other softwares tab uncheck first three options which are cdrom with Ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04 and etc.