# Upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from version 12.10 to 13.04 and when i open my software updater it tells me to Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection. . So I closed it, opened up Firefox. My Internet is working just fine. I even rebooted and tried again a couple of times. It still says to Check Your Internet Connection. I also trued disconnecting and reconnecting my Internet, rebooting the modem. Still nothing. Any advice?

When I click Details, the following shows up:

```
W:GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120817.3)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120817.3)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

.

Comment: Can you please specify the exact error that the Software Updater is displaying? Is it really only "Check your Internet connection" and nothing else, or is there anything else that you didn't mention?

Comment: Exact words are:  Failed to download respository information. Check your internet connection.  I can copy & paste the details part as well?

Comment: please do so and edit your question to add the exact faults.

Comment: Melanie, as @BrunoPereira advised, you should include complete details of the error message you're receiving. Only then we can fully help you through this.

Comment: Please check if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141512/how-to-resolve-failed-to-download-repository-information) could help you.


  [1]:

Comment: @melanie try to update from terminal using sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

First things first. The error you're getting has actually nothing to do with your internet connnection (I know, I know, it's very mis-leading). That error actually will not even stop you from updating at all. To get rid of it, open your 'Software & Updates' application, select the 'Other Software' tab and un-check 'CD-ROM with Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise Pangolin''. Try running the update now and let us know if you're still seeing any errors.

Next, in order to upgrade your Ubuntu to the newest version, you should also check in the 'Software & Updates' app the 'Updates' tab and make sure that under 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version', it says 'For any new version'. If it does, switch over to terminal (press `ctrl+alt+t`), and type this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Afterwards just follow the on-screen instructions.

And, of course, be extra cautious when you're upgrading your system. You should know what every single step is doing to your computer, because if you don't, chances are you'll lose important data (or even mess up your OS installation).