# Failed to download repository information, check your internet connection

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

though i have connected to internet, when tried to update manager, it is showing this message. due to this, there is an error displaying on desktop at top right corner .. can any one help me to resolve this prblem.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt-get update`, are you cable and/or WI-Fi connected to net. Does everything else works properly (browsers, email client, etc)?

Comment: When i do sudo apt-get update, the following msg is showing after updating for sometime...

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100816.1)/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

Comment: W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100816.1)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: its 10.04 or 12.04, in error its lucid how?

Comment: From his post I understood he's still using Lucid.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the other Q, though it appears very close, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, try this solution:

- Go to Ubuntu Software Center, Chose <kbd>Edit</kbd> menu -> then chose Software Sources (last item in that menu). In software sources pop-up window under tab *Ubuntu Software* on bottom where is installable from CD-ROOM/DVD section uncheck *Cd-room with Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid Lynx".*
   Make sure on second tab *Other Software* that check-box for *Cd-room with Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid Lynx"* is unchecked too.
- Run `sudo apt-get update` and problem should be solved.
- Now if you're using desktop edition of 10.04 Lucid Lynx note that the support for this version of Ubuntu stopped in April 2013, so update to newer version (if you like LTS versions 12.04 would be the choice). If you run server edition 10.04 Lucid Lynx is supported till April 2015

Hope It solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It resolved the above said problem. But How can I update LTS version 12.04?

Comment: How can I know the version of ubuntu?

Comment: Glad it helped. To check Ubuntu version press `Ctrl + Alt + t` when terminal comes up this command  will show your distribution ID, description, release and codename  information `lsb_release -a`