# Problems updating

Tags: 18.04, heroku

I am quite new to Ubuntu, starting on 17.10 and am now on 18.04.

On my laptop I have 16.04 which updates perfectly, but on my desktop under 18.04 nothing seems to update automatically.

main error is "Failed to download repository information" "check your internet connection"

I have followed this thread [How to resolve "Failed to download repository information"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141512/how-to-resolve-failed-to-download-repository-information/293066)

Chose "Best server" then "Main server" but still nothing really want to update.

One extra error I see is

> E:Repository 'https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./
>   InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Heroku, Inc.' to 'Heroku'

Under Synaptic though I have managed to update Sublime Text, and also Nvidia driver through a tutorial and console.

But I am yet very new to Ubuntu.

Can someone points the error that prevent `Software and update` to update properly ?

(I have done everything mentioned in above thread : `sudo apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`it kinda works in console but with some warnings at the end)

**EDIT**

here is error on `sudo apt-get update`

```
E: Repository 'https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Heroku, Inc.' to 'Heroku'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

and error on `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
E: Failed to fetch https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/heroku_6.16.18-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 52.85.219.14 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**EDIT 2**

I have tried to install Ubuntu as advised here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

with

`sudo snap install heroku --classic`

but got error

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Exécuter la configuration du point d'accroche du paquet Snap "heroku" s'il est présent (run hook "configure": /usr/local/bin/heroku: ligne 18 : cd: « HOME » non défini)
```

though `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh` seemed to work ans installed the newest version.

Yet the above errors from EDIT section still appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it looks like something has changed at the Heroku repository.  They may have updated the key which would explain the difference between "Heroku" and "Heroku, Inc."

To do an update, the simplest thing is to disable the repository.  You can do this via the GUI or by simply commenting out the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or renaming the file in the `/etc/apt/sourced.list.d` folder.

To solve your heroku update, you'll need to find the right repos URL from heroku and add the new key.

Comment: thank you I will try what you have advised. The problem above refers to Heroku heroku_6.16.18-1_amd64.deb. Now I have done `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh` my heroku version is `heroku/7.7.7 linux-x64 node-v10.7.0`. Maybe I should get rid of heroku_6.16.18-1_amd64

Comment: Yes.  It looks like you're doing an unplanned upgrade from their perspective.  So I'd just remove all references to version 6.16 in apt.

Comment: oddly synaptic does not refer to 7.7.7 but only to 6.16.18-1. By disabling the repository, is it through Software & update > Other software, then removing `https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt./` ?

Comment: Yes.  That will work.  Then do an `apt update` and then you can run the curl script again which will install the correct repository.

Comment: Fantastic. It now works. Nothing had been updated since march when I installed 18.04. Now a lot of things have been updated. Triggered quite a few dpkg (?) errors about packages not configured yet but it seems the update at least work. It says my system is up-to-date.

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, you should update regularly or switch on automatic updates for security reasons. :)

Comment: It was indeed set up as such. I guess the problem with Heroku just blocked it all. Very strange. I get also `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` when I do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` but well everything works fine at the moment and is updated. So it's ok.

Comment: I will still ask a new question to know if someone actually knows a bit more about this. just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Best do an `apt-get -f install`, then.  If you're still getting dpkg errors after that, best list the error as a question.

Comment: Yep still same error. I will log a new question in case someone knows. Many thanks