# All updates on my Ubuntu 16.04 system are failing to install on my

Tags: systemd

Updates on my Ubuntu 16.04 system are failing to load. I have run apt-get update to no avail. I get a message "Failed to download repository information"
8-8-18 10:25. And I'm pretty sure I will be told off for adding the following as it's probably in the wrong place.
I have tried the following:

Assure cdrom is unchecked then cut and paste entire set of below commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`  
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

The above has made no difference. The system still rejects updates. I'm completely stuck.

Comment: We might need some more information than this? Could you post the output when running sudo apt-get update and the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/141512/how-to-resolve-failed-to-download-repository-information/293066